# The most natural ways to invite a person somewhere

Tags: phrase-choice

Which one of the following sentences sounds more natural to you native speakers if you want to invite someone to a cinema:

> -1- **What is your opinion about** going to the movie theater?
>
> -2- What **do you think about** going to the movie theater?
>
> -3- What **do you think of** going to the movie theater?
>
> -4- How **do you like** going to the movie theater?
>
> -5- **How do you feel about** going to the movie theater?
>
> -6- **How about** going to the movie theater?

[Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=what%20is%20your%20opinion%20about%2Cwhat%20do%20you%20think%20about%2Cwhat%20do%20you%20think%20of%2Chow%20do%20you%20like%2Chow%20do%20you%20feel%2Chow%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhat%20is%20your%20opinion%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20do%20you%20think%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20do%20you%20think%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20do%20you%20like%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20do%20you%20feel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chow%20about%3B%2Cc0) I found their hierarchical usage, but I doubt which one is used in this specific sentence by a native.

Comment: None sound natural to me.  Let's go watch a movie!  Let's go see a movie!

Comment: At least in my experience (US native) people rarely say "movie theater" in this context - it's almost always "go see a movie" or "go to a movie". Since you're suggesting going somewhere, the "theater" part is implied.

Comment: Number 3 sounds better. Again, in the USA it is more common to say "going to the movies". We mostly use theatre if we are going to see a play.

Answer (score 2):

What sounds natural depends on the context:

If you and a buddy are looking for something to do:

> How about a movie?

If your partner is upset:

> In know you're disappointed about the ballet getting cancelled.  How do you feel about going to a movie?

1-4 are asking more about someone's opinion of the concept of going to a movie theater, not to actually go to a theater.

Comment: What about #5? What does it mean? I though at least #5 is like the first 4 sentences. And please let e know if the first 4 sentences mean the same.

Comment: #5 is my second example.